# Simple tool for python GUI design full compatible with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, spyder

I am trying to develop a GUI in python, but I am finding some difficulties in designing the interface. I'd like to have some quick design tools, that allow me to add controls with drag and drop actions, and that autogenerate a design code compatible with *tkinter*. I'm interested in a free, simple and straightforward tool (offline or online) that allows me to integrate basic controls and matplotlib objects for data acquisition and monitor in real-time.
Thank you all, in advance!

Comment: FYI this is getting close votes because you are asking a recommendation question, which is against this site's guidelines: [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

First of all you might think that a GUI is the easy part after you wrote your backend code , but it's not.Creating interactive and beautiful interfaces have a lot of work,but actually can be a good initiative on learning OOP,threading and other issues you sometimes won't stumble upon at your first coding years.

One thing thats it's true is that you must have some pretty good experience to just code the design and layouts in an editor without visualization, and it's true that this can save you a lot of time.

Sadly Tkinter as of my knowldge don't have the type of programms you ask,but other libraries have.
Tkinter is a great standard library to make a GUI,but if you really aim to make a professional-level GUI i wouldn't recommend it.
I highly suggest you switch to PyQt5(current version is PyQt6 but i haven't work with it) or PySide libraries that offer more capabilities and also provides free software(QtCreator and QtDesigner) that have drag and drop design programms that can be generated straight to python code.